# How can i extract the value of cluster from below line

Tags: text-processing

I want to extract the value of `clusterName="BYSL_Dev"` from the below line

```
<xmi:id="test.cim " name="test" clusterName="BYDev" developmentMode="false" parallelStartEnabled="true"> <stateManagement xmi:id="StateManageable_1257282383109" initialState="START"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For http or xml files, a tool like [sgrep](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jjaakkol/sgrep.html) works much better than `sed` or `awk`. Use e.g.

```
sgrep '"clusterName=\""__"\""' your-file.xml
```

You can refine the matching if you want to restrict it to the inside of certain tags etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response , But I don't have sgrep installed in my system .

Comment: Do you know any other way like using AWK or SED ,Above Command did not worked for me

Comment: When I Ran command I got

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` works for me:

```
sed -r 's/.*name=".*" (.*") d.*/\1/' cluster 
clusterName="BYSL_Dev"
```

Where `cluster` is this file:

```
cat cluster 
<xmi:id="manish.cim " name="manish" clusterName="BYSL_Dev" developmentMode="false" parallelStartEnabled="true"> <stateManagement xmi:id="StateManageable_1257282383109" initialState="START"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but it says

Comment: I tried this but it says sed: illegal option --r